# Merge or concatenate mdf files asammdf

Tags: python, mdf, asammdf

I am trying to merge some mdf files using asammdf python package. When using MDF.concatenate I get this error:

```
asammdf.blocks.utils.MdfException: internal structure of file 1 is different; different channels
```

The files are from a data logger, and all have almost the same internal structure except 1 or two new channels can be created on some files, I think this is what is creating the error. I have tried using MDF.stack but this doesnt produce the correct result. Is there a way to concatenate the files and only use select channels? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to remove the "extra" signals from the files. (you can use the filter method for example)